# Python Pandas reading csv file - Need to delimit the first data item by _

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter, tokenize

I am trying to read a csv file through python pandas.read_csv() method. If if specify delimiter="_" in the argument, I am getting an error. Appreciate your suggestions.

Code:

```
pandas.read_csv('D:/Coding/data/Sample.csv',header=None,delimiter="_")
```

CSV data format:

```
Company1_A_EPS5,2016-03-31,-0.31,-0.31
```

Error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 309, saw 4
```

Comment: What is your data in line 309? I think the no. of `_` in that line differs from others and cause the error.

Comment: Why is the delimiter `_`?

Comment: Your delimiter in the above data is ',' not '_'. You should load the data using ',' and then use string manipulation on the first column to remove or edit the underscores.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that only "," can be a delimiter and "Company1_A_EPS5" had to be split through separate operation.